# Why do I have these warnings with Jena 2.11.0?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, warnings, jena

I am using Eclipse and Java. I've setup the jena library and done my first RDF statement using this library, but I get a warning and I don't know exactly what it means.
This is the code:

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDatatype;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        String NS = "http://www.example.org/rdf/";
        Resource r = m.createResource(NS + "r");
        Property p = m.createProperty(NS + "p");
        r.addProperty(p, "hello world", XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
        m.write(System.out, "Turtle");
    }

}
```

And this is the output:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jena.riot.stream.JenaIOEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
<http://www.example.org/rdf/r>
        <http://www.example.org/rdf/p>  "hello world"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> .
```

So the code does compile and work but I don't know what to do about this warning.
How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Did you read http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig ?

Comment: So how do I load the log4j.properties file in eclipse?
This is how Jena looks like: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27349592/jena_snapshot.png

Comment: If you make it a resource to be copied into the `bin` directory, it should be fine.

Comment: I have found the file needed. It's called "jena-log4j.properties". What do I have to do with it?
Can you please explain to me step by step?

Comment: No, I've never even used Jena - but I suspect you just want a log4j.properties file rather than jena-log4j.properties

Comment: This is not specific to Jena; it's log4j setup.  Put "log4j.properties" into src/ which will do as Jon suggests.  Or add static { Log.setCmdLogging() ; } to your file which loads Jena command line log4j setup.  Or ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem.
Thanks to [AndyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757100/andys) for the solution.

Copy the "jena-log4j.properties" file inside the folder of the application and add the following line of code at the start of the main:

```
Log.setLog4j("jena-log4j.properties");
```

Comment: It causes this error:
    `The method setLog4j(String) is undefined for the type Log`

Answer (score 1):

The answer that has been provided by Ariel has a  problem. Actually when we write the code `Log.setLog4j("jena-log4j.properties");` it arises the following error:

```
The method setLog4j(String) is undefined for the type Log
```

But you can find a better answer here:

[Configure Eclipse for Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365204/configure-eclipse-for-log4j)

You just need to copy the file `jena-log4j.properties` in the folder that your main class is placed. i.e. the class that has the main function.

Then you need to rename the file to `log4j.properties`.

I did it in Eclipse and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `jena-log4j.properties` file inside the jena folder and paste it to resource folder (in case of eclipse how to guide to add resource folder is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935114/2341815)). Then rename it as `log4j.properties`.