# How do I add a resources folder to my Java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, resources, project-organization

I want to have a place to store my image files to use in my Java project (a really simple class that just loads an image onto a panel). I have looked everywhere and cannot find how to do this. How do I do this?

I have tried adding a new folder to the project, adding a new class folder to the project, and adding a new source folder to the project. No matter what I do, I always get a `IOException`. The folders always say they are on the build path, so I'm not sure what to do.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PracticeFrame extends JFrame{

private static BufferedImage image;
Thread thread;

public PracticeFrame() {
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    PracticeFrame pframe = new PracticeFrame();
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("/islands.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void  paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
        }
    };

    panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    panel.repaint();
    pframe.add(panel);


}


}
```

EDIT: Something that worked for me, and I have no idea why, was adding the `main/res/` folder as a class folder and then removing it.  I ran it while the `/main/res/` was part of the build path as a class folder and it still didn't work. When i added it, i got a popup that told me something about excluded filters. But when i removed the folder from the libraries in the build path, and changed my file path to:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/main/res/islands.png"));
```

I at least stopped getting the `IOException` thrown. I must not be adding the image to the panel correctly, because it's not showing up, but at least it found the file (I think).

Comment: Show the code that produces the exception. You probably specify incorrect path.

Comment: @PM77-1 that is the code I've used for each different way of adding the res folder

Comment: Please post your project directory structure and let us know your destination for  `.class` files.

Comment: I have everything set up like this right now:

workspace/JFramePractice/src/main/res/islands.png

my .class files are here:

workspace/JFramePractice/bin/*.class

Comment: Right Click on your project > New > Source Folder

Answer (score 80):

When at the "Add resource folder", 
Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Source (Tab) -> Add Folder -> Create new Folder
[image]

add "my-resource.txt" file inside the new folder.
Then in your code:

```
    InputStream res =
    Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/my-resource.txt");

    BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    reader.close();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think this is a right answer, the author really doesnt know about how to add resources to a proyecto. He need to know how to open in from the code.

Comment: You should add more informations. Please explain what the OP did wrong and why (especially *how*) your code fixes the problem.

Comment: Ok, in the original example, readagle try to open the file with File class, then you have to provide a path starting from the executable is running, whether or not a resource.
If you open a resource with getResourceAsStream(), it will be open from project resources folder.

Comment: Great information, now go ahead, edit your post and put the info there ;-)

Comment: but this isn't what my question is about. I'm trying to figure out how to add resources folders to Eclipse projects, and that means any project, not just this one. I just used this as an example because it happened to be what I was working on at the time.

Comment: getClass().getResource("/file.txt") has worked for me

Comment: what does build path mean? i downvoted because i have no idea where that is - can you be more specific?

Comment: Why does /myfile.txt work and not /resources/myfile.txt ?

Comment: It is about how to create a file named resource, not how to mark a file as a resource one.

Answer (score 16):

**To answer your question posted in the title of this topic...**

Step 1--> Right Click on Java Project, Select the option "Properties"
[image: Step 1--> Right Click on Java Project, Select the option "Properties"]

Step 2--> Select "Java Build Path" from the left side menu, make sure you are on "Source" tab, click "Add Folder"
[image: Select "Java Build Path" from the left side menu, make sure you are on "Source" tab, click "Add Folder"]

Step 3--> Click the option "Create New Folder..." available at the bottom of the window
[image: Click the option "Create New Folder..." available at the bottom of the window]

Step 4--> Enter the name of the new folder as "resources" and then click "Finish"
[image: Enter the name of the new folder as "resources" and then click "Finish"]

Step 5--> Now you'll be able to see the newly created folder "resources" under your java project, Click "Ok", again Click "Ok"
[image: Now you'll be able to see the newly created folder "resources" under your java project, Click "Ok", again Click "Ok"]

Final Step --> Now you should be able to see the new folder "resources" under your java project
[image: Now you should be able to see the new folder "resources" under your java project]

Comment: ...And it is set as a SOURCE folder, not a RESOURCE one. That is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries (Tab) -> Add Class Folder, then select your folder or create one.

Comment: This answer worked for me! None of the answers above worked! None of the answers in any other thread worked either!

Answer (score 4):

After adding a resource folder try this :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("test.png");

try {
    image = ImageIO.read(input);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If aim is to create a **resources** folder parallel to **src/main/java**, then do the following:

```
Right Click on your project > New > Source Folder
Provide Folder Name as src/main/resources
Finish
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project > Click on properties > Java Build Path > Source > Add Folder

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple sub-projects then you need to add the resources folder to each project's run configuration class path like so:

[image: class path]

Ensure the new path is top of the entries and then the runtime will check that path first for any resources (before checking sub-paths)

Answer (score -1):

Try To Give Full path for reading image.

Example
 image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/work1/Jan14Stackoverflow/src/Strawberry.jpg"));

your code is not producing any exception after giving the full path.
If you want to just read an image file in java code.
Refer the following - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java

If the object of your class is created at end your code works fine for me and displays the image

```
// PracticeFrame pframe = new PracticeFrame();//comment this

new PracticeFrame().add(panel);
```

Comment: Initialise your class at the end

Comment: new PracticeFrame().add(panel);