# How do I load a .wav file from a jar file without the resources in the same directory as the jar file

Tags: java

Whenever I open my .jar file, the sound will not work unless the files are in a folder titled "res" in the same directory as the .jar file. Now it will now work regardless of where the res folder is
 Here's my code

```
try {
         InputStream defaultSound = Game.class.getResourceAsStream("/TrailsGameMusic.wav");
         // getClass().getSy.getResource("/images/ads/WindowsNavigationStart.wav");

         System.out.println("defaultSound " + defaultSound);  // check the URL!
         AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultSound);
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         clip.open(audioInputStream);
         clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where are the wave files stored in the jar file?  Have tried unzipping the jar file to verify that they are included in the jar file?

Comment: I now took the advice of m.aibin and changed my code to

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem with absolute path:
If you declare it like that: `"/res/TrailsGameMusic.wav"`, you are referring to absolute path - it works. If you will write only `"TrailsGameMusic.wav"`, it will be a relative path - it will not work.

You can configure your resources using for example this link:
[How do I add a resources folder to my Java project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse)