# adding image in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to add image in java swing, I wrote a simple code with out any error in the code(l also tried ("rr.png") instead ("c:\rr.png") but in both situation I got this when l want run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at quize1.uml.<init>(uml.java:14)
   at quize1.uml.main(uml.java:20)
```

Here is my code:

```
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;

  public class uml extends JFrame {

  private ImageIcon image2;
  private JLabel Label2;
   public uml() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("c:\\rr.png"));
    Label2 = new JLabel( image2);
    add (Label2);
    }

   public static void main(String arg[]) {
    uml gui = new uml();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("uml ");

   }}
```

Comment: Put your image files in the resource folder, not in your C drive. Then you can access it by just calling `getClass().getResource("rr.png")`.

Comment: @KeqiangLi please can you tell me what exactly mean by resource folder, thank you.

Comment: say you are using Eclipse, check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse):

Comment: @KeqiangLi appreciate your help, please can you write answer in order to tick it as a right answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: No need to, I'll just mark this question as a duplicate one. :)