# How to open a file independently of the path of the Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, path

I'm working with Eclipse and there, I have Java Project with the name "Test" which also contains text files. A class in this Project should be able to read in one of these files with a BufferedReader. This is my current code for that:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/workspace/Test/testFile.txt"));
```

My file is always in the Project, but when I move the Project to another path, the file path changes, too, so I have to adjust the code with the new path.
I dont't want that, because it's impractical, so what can I do? How can I get the path of the Project?

Comment: Why do you have to move the file at first if it is required for the project?It is better to add the file as a resource to your project and access from the current path.

Comment: A simple solution would be to use relative path like "./testFile.txt". Keep in mind that this is relative to the directory from where you started the application.

Comment: I move my Project which contains the file.

Comment: In this case you can put the file in the resource folder of the project and use the class loader to get the file from there.

Answer (score 1):

[You can add file to resources folder and read like](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("file/test.xml").getFile());
```

Comment: I have created  a new "resources" folder and put the file there. Then I used your code and do   in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));   but it doesn't works!

Comment: You need to add the resources folder to the build path as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
File currentDirFile = new File(".");
String fileDir = currentDirFile.getAbsolutePath();
```