# How to include resource folder in executable .jar file in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I need to create an application for sorting various types of polygons using various parameters such as height, volume or base area. Arguments for Filename which has parameters for polygons, Sort type, Sort method will be pass through command line.That file is in my resource folder outside my src folder in a project. I have implemented all programs, It works fine when I run using pass arguments through eclipse run configuration. But when I try to run my .jar file using cmd same arguments it gives me `FileNotFoundException`.

I opened my jar file using `7zip` and noticed it never extracted my resource folder in .jar file. I searched online and tried including my resource folder in to build path of eclipse. But still does't work.

[image]

Comment: Is the resources folder checked in "Order and Export" tab in "Java Build Path"?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it. It is checked and exporting into jar file but now it is exporting all files separately, not as a folder. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Try selecting "Add directory entries" in the Eclipse export dialog (the screen where you enter JAR file name)

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1) click project -> properties -> Build Path -> Source -> Add Folder and select  resources folder.

2) create your JAR!

EDIT: you can make sure your JAR contains folder by inspecting it using 7zip.

Reefer this link as well [How do I add a resources folder to my Java project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I just tried it. But it add files separately instead of resources folder. And still FileNotFoundException occurs.

Comment: After following your EDIT tip, I learned that even though your resource file, e.g. `someFile.txt` is located in `<YourProjectName>/src/main/resource/<yourpackagename>/someFile.txt`, the location you have to access it at, is:
`<yourpackagename>/someFile.txt`. (As one can see after inspecting the `.jar` file with winrar/7zip.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to create a source folder for resources, for instance name it *res*, and then move your image folder to res. When you generate the jar file, you will see the image folder, not the *res* folder or files separately.

[image: resource folder]

Comment: That solve the issue of exporting Resources folder. But the images does not load.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to how you are generating the JAR file.

When you're exporting the jar in eclipse make sure to checkbox the button that says "Export java sources and resources" https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/ensureJavaFiles.jpg

There are a lot of ways to do this one is to use Gradle is the recommended way, something like this will work [Creating runnable JAR with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721119/creating-runnable-jar-with-gradle)