# problem running a jar designed with java and javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to export my java and javafx code as a ruunable file, but when executing the jar I get a message that says java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required. '(You can see in the link that leaves the complete error below), the problem is that if I run the code in the same eclipse if it opens the created program without any problem, but when I export it, the jar does not open.
I leave the main.java class that connects with the javafx.

On the other hand, I saw that a solution was to add getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("main.fxml") but that way I don't run the program in eclipse, so I have to leave it as getClass().getResource(" Main.fxml ")) to run in the editor.

Now, to export as a jar a java file with javafx is it exported normal or do other steps have to be followed?

```
public class Main extends Application {
        
        private double xOffset = 0;
        private double yOffset = 0;
        
        @Override
        public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {

                AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
                stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                scene.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
                
                
                root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                        yOffset = event.getSceneY();
                    }
                });
                
                //Permite el movimiento
                root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                        stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
                    }
                });
                
                
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

**image** [errorImage](https://ibb.co/FVKbWsZ)

**FOLDER Structure** [folder structure](https://ibb.co/pL4D01T)

**In jar**
[image]

**In IDE ECLIPSE:**
[image]

Comment: Look like the file is not there. Check if below Post helps - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266492/location-is-required-exception-when-loading-fxml-file

Comment: I just added a link that shows the image of how the folders are structured and thus arrive at the file.

Comment: How are you running the code? From IDE or using jar?

Comment: from IDE eclipse

Comment: If I add a syso in the column where the fxml file is called, in eclipse the path appears but when exporting it in jar it doesn't.

Comment: So the program errors when you run it using Jar. Can you check the content of jar if file is there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100605/how-to-include-resource-folder-in-executable-jar-file-in-eclipse/47100985 should help

Comment: thanks my friend, I was able to solve the problem, I had to create a folder called resource and there add file.

Comment: no screenshots of text