# JavaFx Image on an fxml file who have a variable url

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have tried to find my answer on google but no results right now.

So i'm sorry if its an already solved post.

What I want to do : When my FXML file is load, I want the imageView in this file to load an image from an URL which is contain in a table of Strings who contains differents URLs, so I can switch the image on load according to my `choice` variable. I have tried with absolute paths and relative paths.

In my main :

```
//url tab of the 2 images
public static String[] images = new String[2];

//variable that include the choice for the image to load in the tab images
public static int choice = 0;

public MainTest() {
    images[0] = "C:/Users/Stagiaire ACI/Desktop/Java/ImageTestImage/Assasin.png";
    images[1] = "C:/Users/Stagiaire ACI/Desktop/Java/ImageTestImage/Barde.png";
}
```

My fxml file controler :

```
@FXML
private ImageView image;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    Image image = new Image(MainTest.images[MainTest.choice]);
    this.image.setImage(image);
}
```

And my Fxml file :

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.test.view.TestControler">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="image" fitHeight="310.0" fitWidth="319.0" layoutX="306.0" layoutY="183.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

So with this i can change `choice` to change the image on load.
My images works well when I load it with the classic way.

Don't even know if it's possible.

Thank you!

EDIT : I have solved my problem by putting `file:` above the file url.

Comment: You can't use `@` or `..` in the path for an image in your Java code. The `Image` constructor  is expecting a URL of the image (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html)).

Comment: I have update my code like I have edit in the question, all in absolute path, but didn't even work.

Comment: In the doc its `Image​(String url)` so Image is waiting a string, and that's what i'm giving to him.  `MainTest.images[MainTest.choice]` is a String.

Comment: ["The Image class represents graphical images and is used for loading images from a specified URL."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html). "All URLs supported by URL can be passed to the constructor. If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case." The string you pass, e.g. `"C:/Users/Stagiaire ACI/Desktop/Java/ImageTestImage/Assasin.png"` does not represent a URL (in particular, it will interpret `C` as the URL scheme).

Comment: So i need to make an URL tab with : 
 `URL url = new URL(yourUrl, "C:/Users/Stagiaire ACI/Desktop/Java/ImageTestImage/Assasin.png");`

Comment: What's wrong with the approaches provided in the answer by fabian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL properties with values starting with `@` are treated differently by `FXMLLoader`. They are treated as relative to the document. This does not work outside of fxmls.

Absolute file paths don't work either since they don't contain a protocol.

If your image is a resource you should use `Class.getResource` and if it's not, use `File.toURI().toURL()`:

```
images[0] = MainTest.class.getResource("/absolute/package/path/Assasin.png").toExternalForm();
images[1] = new File("C:/Users/Stagiaire ACI/Desktop/Java/ImageTestImage/Barde.png").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the deference between the 2 ways, and when i'm trying both of them, neither works.

Is that because I need to make a Tab of File instead of Strings?

Comment: @AtraWanderer "Resource" is something that is part of the project, i.e. bundled with your application. "Not a resource" would be, for example, something on the end user's file system (an image that is not part of the project).

Comment: My images are located on a source folder so I understand that they are a Resource : https://imgur.com/a/mozlg

So they are not in a package, they are in the project file.
That's why I don't know what to put in : `"/absolute/package/path/Assasin.png"`

Comment: @AtraWanderer If they are in the root of the classpath, then simply `"/Assasin.png"`.

Comment: It still makes me an error, am I used to put `MainTest.class.getResource("/Assasin.png").toExternalForm();` into a String tab?

Comment: This answer describes adding a folder with a text file to a java project in eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935114/2991525 `getResourceAsStream` and `getResource` work with the same parameter.

Comment: Have you got an example beacause of what i have read/learn, my file Images in the project file is always load and I just have to read on `/Barde.png` to get it. Realy thank you for the help!

Comment: I have tried to put "../../../Image/Barde.png" to get it, it's the relative path from the mainTest class where is the code `images[0] = MainTest.class.getResource("../../../Image/Assasin.png").toExternalForm();` is. But you sayed that relative paths aren't useable that's it?