# NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null putting a image in a button in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

My code is in something like this:

```
project/src/com/controller/controller.java
```

And the image is in

```
 project/resources/user/default_browser.png
```

Shouldn´t I reach the image with this route

```
        Image imageOk = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../../resources/user/default_browser.png"));
        btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageOk));
```

Comment: please read the api doc of getResourceAsStream - it doesn't mention that it supports anything like "../../", does it :)

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the `resources` directory are put at the root of your jar file, so you should access them as follows:

```java
Image imageOk = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("user/default_browser.png"));
btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageOk));
```

Comment: still get "Input stream must not be null"

Comment: Use folder sturcture like `src/main/java/com/controller/controller.java` and `src/main/resources/user/default_browser.png`. Then try as @Sergei mentioned - `getClass().getResourceAsStream("user/default_browser.png")`

Comment: This is only valid if OP uses Maven as their build tool. @danielgon can you clarify what build system do you use (Maven, Gradle, Eclipse, IDEA...?)

Comment: I´m in Eclipse, not using Maven

Comment: Did you create the project from some kind of a template? Or did you just create the `resources` directory yourself? To add the directory to the classpath of a running application, Eclipse has to "know" about it, so you need to add this directory to the build path. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse

Comment: `"user/default_browser.png"` is a relative path but from the question it looks the the `Class` is in a different package than the resource. @danielgon What if you try `"/user/default_browser.png"`?