# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json on Java QuickStart for Classroom API

Tags: credentials, ioexception, google-classroom

I have implemented the Java QuickStart for the Classroom API and am getting an error message "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json" at run-time.  I copied my credentials.json file to the Project res directory, but continue to get this error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Double check the file name and path.

Comment: Did you create a folder "src/main/java/" and are both your .java file and your credentials.json file inside this folder?

Answer (score 5):

I tried it in a different way than I found on other websites, and it worked for me.

replace below code:

```
InputStream in = GoogleSheetAPIHandler.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```

With this code:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import credential.json file into the src/main/resources folder in eclipse. You may be included in the project folder. But you need to import it into eclipse.

- locate your credentials.json file in the folder.
- click and drag it
- drop it in src/main/resource and click ok.
- After importing into eclipse it should show like the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps needed to find the resource in Eclipse:

1. To have the file in the resources folder

   - Create the resource folder (if it does not exist): **src/main/resouces**
   - Add the credential file to the resource folder: **src/main/resouces/credential.json**
2. To have the resources folder in the Source Java Build Path

   - Go to Eclipse Path Source: **Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source (tab)**
   - Add resources folder: **Add Folder ... (button) > resources (check box) > OK (button)**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46950488/10850340

Answer (score 0):

The name of your file has to be credentials only, if you have credentials.json as the name of your file in your folder you will get this error.