# Resource not found: /credentials.json Google Sheets API

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api, credentials

I follow the google Sheets quickstart and download the `credentials.json` put in my project main/res.
No matter how I change the place, it always shows the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json`

I have tried the other way that I found in this post:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json on Java QuickStart for Classroom API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292883/java-io-filenotfoundexception-resource-not-found-credentials-json-on-java-qui)

But still the same.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it? I google it for a long time. Thanks
[image]

Comment: What quickstart are you following? [This one](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java)? If that's the case, the file should be in `src/main/resources/`, as explained there.

Comment: Hi, I follow the Google Sheets v4, but I'm developing an app in the android studio.I thought just put in my app folder. is it wrong?

Comment: Sorry I meant to reference the sheet one: [Java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java). But that doesn't change the point, the OAuth process is the same for both APIs. The credentials should be in `src/main/resources/`. That's where the app is looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the `credentials.json` file in the main app folder but, as you can see in the corresponding [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) for Sheets API, this file should be in `src/main/resources/`.

Your issue should be solved by moving the file to the specified location.

Comment: I move to src/main/res, still the same. or I should create an asset folder call "resourcrs"?? I update the picture on the post.

Comment: Are you following the referenced quickstart? Did you build the project via `gradle run`? Can you provide the code related to the authorization process?

Comment: Sorry, no. I do it and then show the error in terminal: Task 'run' not found in root project 'PhoneCallReminder'.

Comment: @PennyChen I thought you were following the `google Sheets quickstart`? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java

Comment: How can I do it in Python? Having the same issue, downloaded the credencials to my main project folder

Answer (score 1):

I use the android studio, and I solved it by created a res/raw folder.

Then moved the credential.json into it.

And use the following code instead to access it.

```java
InputStream in = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);
```