# Resource not found /credentials.json

Tags: java, selenium, gmail, gmail-api

I have an issue with Gmail API.

I did everything the same as is described in the following link: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#prerequisites

I'm using Windows 8.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json
        at GmailQuickstart.getCredentials(GmailQuickstart.java:46)
        at GmailQuickstart.main(GmailQuickstart.java:63)
```

I already tried the solution from this link but it doesn't fix the problem: [java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found: /credentials.json on Java QuickStart for Classroom API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292883/java-io-filenotfoundexception-resource-not-found-credentials-json-on-java-qui)

Comment: Side note: Is the `selenium` tag directly relevant to your problem? If not, you should remove it from the question. If it is (or may be) relevant, maybe you can [edit] the question and clarify how?

Comment: do you have the credentials.json file generated from GCP? where do you have it located locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the path in your code as src/main/java src/main/resources/credentials.json  instead of /credentials.json