# Close window after checking

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a slight issue, and I can't figure it out.
I want for my code to check if the email and password matches and *then* close the window. This the action:

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        boolean status = Email_Verification.email_validation(email_text.getText().toString().trim());
        if (status) {
            lbl_inco_email.setText(null);
        } else {
            lbl_inco_email.setText("Please enter a valid email");
        }

        boolean stat = Password_Verification.password_validation(password_Field.getPassword().toString());
        if (stat) {
            lbl_inco_pwd.setText(null);
        }   else {
            lbl_inco_pwd.setText("Please enter a valid Password");
        }

        /*      Exit and redirect to the main application if the email/pwd matches the database */

        /** MAIN__WINDOW __EXIT__ONCLICK__ = new MAIN__WINDOW();
        __EXIT__ONCLICK__.setVisible(true); */
    }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps try an [`InputVerifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification), examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20InputVerifier)?

Comment: @trashgod Can you check a question based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696609/how-do-i-change-image-icon-of-a-jframe?noredirect=1#comment121447160_68696609) which mentions a frame icon not working on Mac? AFAIR you have provided screenshots suggesting Mac does not use custom frame icons. (I may be incorrectly recalling the details, though.)

Comment: OP: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. Note expecially that the only case where the `_` character is part of the common nomenclature is for a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you have an issue with opening a new frame and disposing of the login frame, because if you have an issue with user validation there isn't enough information for any of us to actually help.

Also, please read this concerning the use of multiple JFrames. [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice)

Now for the code section...

Once user validation is done, you need to create an instance of your main window and make it visible. After that you can close the first JFrame.

Your actionPerformed would look something like this:

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       // Let's assume you have a boolean variable that handles user validation 
          //for simplicity...
       if(userVerified) {
         // In this example let's call the main application window MainFrame
          MainFrame mF = new MainFrame();
          // Set it to visible
          mF.setVisible(true);
          mF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          // Now you can close the first JFrame
          this.dispose();
       }
    }
});
```