# java class getResource can't find icons listed in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, getresource

I am really stumped. I'm just an old C X11/Motif programmer trying to write a little Java program. After a week of reading [the Oracle Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)),  as well as the
Stack Overflow answers related to getResource, I still can not figure out how to retrieve the path to the icon files in my jar file.

My icons are contained within the jar file for my application. I wish to access them using the relative position within jar file. I am assuming the best way to do this is through the getResource method.

The core part of my code for my program called ***Fŭd*** (pronounced food - like the cat spells it in the comic strip "*Get Fuzzy*") is as follows:

```
package localhost.system1;

imports not shown for brevity.

public class Fud extends JPanel
             implements FocusListener, ActionListener, ItemListener
  {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;
    static Food                 data                = null;
    static int                  prev                = 0;
    static int                  next                = 1;
    static int                  plus                = 2;
    static int                  minus               = 3;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
        LocalDate           now             = LocalDate.now();
        int                 dateDifference  = 0;

        // load in the existing data
        data = new Food(programName);
        data.loadFood(programName);
      
        // test to see if data is up to date. Add days if not
        dateDifference = Math.abs((int)ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now, data.day[0].date));
    if ( dateDifference != 0)
      {
        data.adjustToToday(dateDifference, programName);
      }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////  
    // create the GUI and switch running over to it. 
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Fud     fud             = new Fud();
    Class<? extends Fud>    fudClass    = fud.getClass();
    

    String  className = fudClass.getName();
    System.out.println("fudClass getname returns " + className);
    
    URL     testURL         = fudClass.getResource("prev.png");
    System.out.println("fudClass getResource returned " + testURL);
    
    // Create GUI and turn the control over to it
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater
      (new Runnable() 
        {
          public void run() 
            {    
              URL[] iconURL     = new URL[4];
              
              iconURL[prev]     = Fud.class.getResource("prev.png");
              iconURL[next]     = Fud.class.getResource("next.png");
              iconURL[plus]     = Fud.class.getResource("plus.png");
              iconURL[minus]    = Fud.class.getResource("minus.png");

              createAndShowGUI(fud, iconURL);
            }
        }
      );
        
  } // end of main

.
.
.
Rest of methods and subroutines  needed
.
.
.
}
```

When run, the code returns the following results:

```
fudClass getname returns localhost.system1.Fud
fudClass getResource returned null
```

This has me quite frustrated. No matter what I try (and I have tried a number of things) the result remains the same. I keep getting NULL for a response from the getResource method. When I query the jar file with `jar -tf Fud.jar` I get the following:

```
jar tf Fud.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
localhost/
localhost/system1/
localhost/system1/Day.class
localhost/system1/Food.class
localhost/system1/Fud$1.class
localhost/system1/Fud$2.class
localhost/system1/Fud$3.class
localhost/system1/Fud$4.class
localhost/system1/Fud$5.class
localhost/system1/Fud$6.class
localhost/system1/Fud$7.class
localhost/system1/Fud.class
minus.png
next.png
plus.png
prev.png
```

So the icons are in the Jar file. **Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?** In Eclipse, my project explorer looks like:[eclipse Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P52sC.jpg)

I added the Image directory to my project Java build in eclipse as follows: [Eclipse Java Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K13EJ.jpg)

I built the program using Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0) Build id: 20211202-1639. Furthermore, I am using Java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS on Windows 11 Pro build 22000.434.

Comment: Read that documentation more closely, especially the two bullet points.  `fudClass.getResource("prev.png")` looks for a jar entry named `localhost/system1/prev.png`.  `fudClass.getResource("/prev.png")` (notice the leading slash in the string) looks for a jar entry named `prev.png`.   (This is by design;  resources are supposed to be inside packages, to reduce the risk of conflicts with other libraries’ jar files.)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a slash in front of the resource:

```
Fud.class.getResource("/prev.png");
```

otherwise java searching in the same folder as the class is located,

so it will search in `localhost/system1`

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to add a backslash, as that is the separator used by Windows. That obviously did not work. I can not believe how much time I have spent on this! I appreciate your taking the time to look this over.