# How can i import a .mp3 file into Eclipse used for an audioClip in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, audioclip

I want to add an AudioClip to my Game. I used Java and JavaFX and wrote my Code in Eclipse.
The error that shows up is

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x5e355576) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x5e355576>

This is the code where i tried to initiliaze my AudioCLip

`public AudioClip OWMusic = new AudioClip(getClass().getResource("/OWMusic.mp3").toExternalForm());`

Comment: Consider making your code [modular](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your project, create a `resources` folder and add the `OWMusic.mp3` file inside. If this does not work, ensure the folder is added to your project's classpath. This last step depends more on your build system (ant/maven/gradle) and less the concise IDE you are using.

See also [How do I add a resources folder to my Java project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse)