# java adding log4j.properties file makes main class not seen

Tags: java, log4j, jena

I have a main class to test some of the functions, I am getting error:

> WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Jena).

I searched online, and I found this answer to solve the problem

[Configure Eclipse for Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365204/configure-eclipse-for-log4j)

One of the answers says that I should create a file called `log4j.properties` in the bin folder. However, when I do that, I get this problem:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.blablabla.Main

If I remove that file from the bin folder, i go back to the first problem.

Comment: How are you initializing the logger???

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa I didn't do anything more than what I wrote in the question. Thus, I may not have initialized the logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do likewise,

put your `log4j.properties` file into resource directory(if you are using `Eclipse IDE` then otherwise put it where it load to your `Runtime Environment`)

and into your `log4j.properties` file set `appender`  properly,
For Example : `log4j.properties` will look like after completely configure,

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.file=${path}/logFile2.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: I put my resources in src/main/resources, should I put the log4j.properties there as well? should I copy what you've wrote to that file as well please?

Comment: please, provide correct location where you want to create your log file. ignore my provided path , '=${path}/logFile2.log' or just type logFile2.log.